# Width of site not 100% full width in all browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The width of my site is not 100% full browser width. I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.1 and handcoded the site without a template:

Site is live at [www.getcitylights.com](http://www.getcitylights.com)

Here's what I have for the CSS for the body and one child element (welcometop) which is the top blue div:

```
  * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }


  html, body {
                min-width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
              }


         .welcometop {
                margin:0;
                min-height:210px;
                max-height:auto;
                background: #1542bd;    
                     }
```

If you scroll to the right, you can see that all of the child elements are not full browser width in both Chrome desktop and mobile.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, "watch" the bootstrap documentation? They are publishing videos now?

Comment: There is no such thing as max-height: auto; and you do not, not ever, set a height or a width or max-width or whatever on you html not body ;)

Comment: your version of bootstrap css doesn't have specifications for the class .container-fluid ^^ load the new version of the css on your server and you should be good

Comment: Thanks @Pinki , can you see the bug where you hover over the middle img and it changes size by 1-2px? Know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

It is the `margin-right:-15px;` from Bootstrap's `.row` class which is applied to a `<div>` in your `#firststop` header causing this issue.

**Solution**

If you aren't going to miss the extra `margin-left` applied to this element when using Bootstrap's `row` class, simply remove the class from the element.

If you want the `margin-left` to be applied, but not the unwanted `margin-right`, don't apply the `.row` class to this element and use your own selector, e.g:

`<div id="example">` instead of `<div class="row">`

And in your own custom.css stylesheet:

```
#example { margin-left:-15px; }
```

Comment: hi @null should I remove the -15px margin from the .row class too?

Comment: @GirlcanCode680 No, just don't apply .row too it, if you want the margin-left still, just use a more specific selector and apply it

Comment: @null ok but thought this was best practice for Bootstrap. Your first suggestion for removing Margin-right:-15px worked

Comment: @GirlcanCode680 That works but it will affect every element with .row, so you are better off just not using .row for this case, or overriding it yourself like my answer states.

Comment: Ok Great. I should also add that I still have the problem on minimized (mobile) view. Any thoughts?

Comment: @GirlcanCode680 That's a different problem, the anthony@citylights text is pushing the width out like that. Have a look at what is being applied to it and apply the idea of my answer to that problem too